# Visual Studio greys out not selected code. How to change that?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio crashed on me and right after it started again something got changed. Now it greys out code that's currently not selected. How can I change that behavior? I haven't found the option, neither did I find a solution online.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgoDF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. The feature causing this behavior is called "focus dimmer" You can find the corrosponding options under Tools > Focus Dimmer.